# Are there theoretical equations for the coefficient of static friction that are based on surface profiles?

Tags: friction

The Coulomb Model of Static Friction conventionally defines the coefficient of static friction as the ratio of the maximum static friction force to the normal force, to be determined experimentally. I was wondering whether there are any research workers involving a theoretical equation for the coefficient of static friction as opposed to empirical ones? I would guess that such equations would involve surface features rather than forces.